# Regex match with Python re from end of line

Tags: python

I'm matching the last word 'City' or 'City City'.

Work's on regex101.com (https://regex101.com/r/7F6Jao/1) but not in Python.

```
folder = i.find ( 'folder' ).text
# Top > Continent > Country > City
    country = re.match ( r'\s+\S*$', folder )
    print ( folder )
```

Output I get 'None'.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `re.search` here, since you don't want your regex pattern to be anchored to the start of the input (which is the default behavior for `re.match`):

```
text = "Top > Continent > Country > City"
p = re.compile("\\b\\S*$")
matches = p.search(text)
if matches:
    print("Found a match: " + matches.group(0))
else:
    print("no match")
```

This prints:

```
Found a match: City
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

In addition for the scenario (for City names with 2 words):

```
# Top > Continent > Country > City City 
p = re.compile("[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+$")
```

Output:

```
City City 
> City
```

Seems like cannot exclude the last '>'.

Maybe match from the left capture everything after 3 '>' plus a space?